# Buffer.BlockCopy - Object must be an array of primitives

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte

i am trying to read data from binary file, i can read all data types except when its an array of strings, i am getting the error " Object must be an array of primitives"

here is where i get the error in my code

```
        binReader.BaseStream.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        buff = binReader.ReadBytes(369);
        string[,,] MyArray = new string[1000, 4, 4];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buff, 0, MyArray , 0, buff.Length);
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: While for primitive ("blittable") types there is a natural representation in a byte buffer, for strings there is not. So the question is: how are your strings layed out in the buffer? With preceding count or with terminating 0? Which encoding (ASCII, UTF8, ...)?

Comment: thats the question, i am doubting that it's cause of the encoding which i am not using any but i can't overcome it when i am reading from the binary file, any chance how to encode while i am reading the data? @KlausGütter

Comment: You must have some idea how the strings are stored in the file. How did you create the file?

Comment: @KlausGütter have no idea to be honest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can see in the documentation of [buffer.blockCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffer.blockcopy?view=netcore-3.1) that it only works on primitive types:

> ArgumentException
>
> src or dst is not an array of primitives.

From [Type.IsPrimitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?view=netcore-3.1) we can see that the primitive types are:

> The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single.

Notably, string is not a primitive type, so cannot be used with blockCopy.

Since the question does not describe how the strings are stored it is difficult to know how to read the data. I would recommend prefixing the data with the array sizes. That way reading would be something like this:

```
    public static string[,,] Read3DArray( BinaryReader binReader)
    {
        var xSize = binReader.ReadInt32();
        var ySize = binReader.ReadInt32();
        var zSize= binReader.ReadInt32();

        var result = new string[xSize, ySize, zSize];
        for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < ySize; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < zSize; z++)
                {
                    result[x, y, z] = binReader.ReadString();
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

If you know the size of the string array you can skip the reading the x/y/z max values.